# How to send hex value to BLE device?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-ble

I am developing one ble application in which as an input I have to give BLE a hex value as a time parameter so that the device will run for that much time. I have tried everything I know but it is not working. Please help me to get a solution.

```
    AppConstants.pulse_time.setWriteType(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_DEFAULT);
                        AppConstants.gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(AppConstants.pulse_time, true);
//                        AppConstants.pulse_time.setValue(3, BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT16, 0);
//                        AppConstants.pulse_time.setValue(toBytes(03));
//                        AppConstants.pulse_time.setValue(toHex(""+3));
//                        AppConstants.pulse_time.setValue("0x2");
//                        AppConstants.pulse_time.setValue(convertStringToHex("32"));
                        AppConstants.pulse_time.setValue("0x"+ Integer.toHexString(2));
//                        AppConstants.pulse_time.setValue(String.format("%02x","2"));
//                        AppConstants.pulse_time.setValue(Integer.toString(2, 16));
//                        AppConstants.pulse_time.setValue(hexStringToByteArray("0x2"));
//                        AppConstants.pulse_time.setValue(31,BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT8,0);
//                        AppConstants.pulse_time.setValue(toBytes(3));
                        AppConstants.gatt.writeCharacteristic(AppConstants.pulse_time);



private String convertStringToHex(String string)
    {
        StringBuilder newString = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i=0; i<string.length(); i++)
        {
            newString.append(String.format("%02X ", (byte)(string.charAt(i))));
        }
        return newString.toString();
    }

    public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
        int len = s.length();
        byte[] data = new byte[(len / 2)];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
            data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4) + Character.digit(s.charAt(i + 1), 16));
        }
        return data;
    }

    public static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
        char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];
        for ( int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++ ) {
            int v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
            hexChars[j * 2] = hexArray[v >>> 4];
            hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = hexArray[v & 0x0F];
        }
        return new String(hexChars);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Good evening, could you please explain more fine-grained which kind of "hex"-value the result should be? You need both functions, for converting between string and hex (hex-number)?

If the code is Java, then refer:

```
public static int convert(int n) {
  return Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(n), 16);
}
```

or:

```
Integer.toHexString(int)
```

I know this is just an integer, not a string. Please explain more, what "AppConstants.pulse_time.setValue" expects as parameter.

Comment: Hello Marcel code is java and "AppConstants.pulse_time is Bluetooth characteristic, to which I am setting value

Comment: Marcel I have tried with your solution but not working